# I am trying to autofill a column based on text in the same row, but the references will be different categories and I'm getting ERROR thrown at me

Tags: currency, autofill

I am trying to code a Google sheet for my mother's book keeping but I am hitting a wall. I have a number of categories that will be referenced and, depending on the category the monetary value will be changing.

Example.
Clerical  $20/hr
Prop Mngt $35/hr
Admin     $50/hr
Plus others I'm not aware of yet

I have tried this code =IF(SEARCH("Administration",$C8)>0,"$50") and it worked for the one keyword.
When I tried =IF(SEARCH("Administration",$C8)>0,"$50"),=IF(SEARCH("Clerical",$C8)>0,"$20") I was given ERROR.

How do I tell C8 to autofill D8 with the correct hourly rate? This will then feed D10 with =SUM(D8*E8)    ???

Thank you for your help. I know just enough to know it's possible but not enough to grasp the issues I'm facing.

Comment: did you try the formula?

Comment: Hi Mike I ended up getting food poisoning on Friday night and I'm just getting back on my feet. I tried it and was given !ERROR#. I'll keep trying other formulas today and see if any of them stick. Thanks for your help. UPDATE I wanted to try and break down the new formula you provided so I could try and understand the steps, and when I try =IF(SEARCH("Administration",$C8)>0,"$50") it gives me #VALUE!

Comment: UPDATE It works if I only have =IF(SEARCH("Administration",$C8)>0,"$50") but when I try to use the entire =IF(SEARCH("Administration",$C8)>0,"$50"),=IF(SEARCH("Clerical",$C8)>0,"$20") it gives me !ERROR#. (I had $C8 blank in the actual sheet when I first tried the formula, apologies)

Comment: This is not the formula I give hereafter. Don't put `=` in the middle of a formula. But there is other mistakes.

Comment: To go further, please give a link to a simplified spreadsheet.

Comment: I have added a screen shot in my answer

Comment: ... and another formula

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IF(not(iserror(SEARCH("Administration",$C8))),"$50",IF(not(iserror(SEARCH("Clerical",$C8))),"$20",""))
```

[image]

Another solution is to use this formula I think more understandable

```
=IFs(not(iserror(SEARCH("Administration",A1))),"$50",not(iserror(SEARCH("Clerical",A1))),"$20")
```